# Qt creator direct file include

Tags: c++, c, qt, include, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 3.2.2 for windows. I have created an example project widget application project and that's okay. The problem is I had to add some external libraries (.c and .h files) that are in the project folder. The problem is they are not all in the same place but mixed in subcatalogs. Qt creator seemed to add them all correctly.

But the problem now is that I cannot use for example:

```
#include <somefile.h>
```

Because it says that there is no such file. Autocomplete also doesn't see it. I have to do:

```
#include <dir/deeper_dir/somefile.h>
```

And the whole library is created the way that every file is reachable from everywhere. Also I would not like to change that.

How can I make all files visible within the project?

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to your headers into your .pro file with `INCLUDEPATH`:

```
INCLUDEPATH += path_to_the_folder_with_your_headers
```

After that you will be able to include any file in that folder just with `#include <filename>`

Answer (score 1):

add

```
INCLUDEPATH += dir/deeper_dir/
```

in your pro file.